# How to know publish is successful in Google Pub Sub using .net library?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-pubsub

I am pushing some data to a topic in Google Pub Sub. Following code pushes a message to the topic:

```
   PublishResponse response = client.Publish(topic, messages);
```

`client` is `PublisherClient` and `message` is a `PubSubMessage`.

Now this `response` object doesn't tell me if the publish was successful or not. I check the API docs:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/api/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.PublishResponse.html

But no help. I am in the middle of a big project, thus I can't run this code and check what all values I can get in `response` object.

Thus it will be great if someone can shed some light on this mystic object `PublishResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Publish method will throw an exception if something fails.

Answer (score 1):

`Publish` method will return `PublishResponse` as an output where `MessageID`s will be populated if messages have been successfully published else if there is any issue in publishing , An exception of Type `RPCException` will be thrown.